# Ring epimorphism $f:R\rightarrow S$, $R$ has finitely many maximal ideals, then $f(J(R))=J(S)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Suppose $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings with unit, and $f:R\rightarrow S$ is an epimorphism. Prove that: $$f(J(R))\subseteq  J(S).$$ If $R$ has finitely many maximal ideals, then prove that:  $$f(J(R))=J(S).$$

I know how to show that $f(J(R))\subseteq  J(S)$ but for the inverse I don't know what should I do, so please help me.

Recall that $J(R)$  is Jacobson radical of $R$.

Comment: What is $J(R)$?

Comment: it is jacobson radical of $R$.

Comment: By "epimorphism" do you mean "surjective homomorphism"?

Comment: yes I do.you're right.

Comment: See this link for more informations http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=S3pZbAByfDgC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=Prove+that+f(rad(R))%3Drad(S).&source=bl&ots=8GjB05lk-5&sig=QVHl9J4H-P-nwUOWgZ8yL7jMu4Q&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=xe62UrbBIObyiAfvm4GoCg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Prove%20that%20f(rad(R))%3Drad(S).&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{m}_i$, i=1,...,n be the set of maximal ideals in $R$. As $f$ is an epimorphism, every maximal ideal in $S$ is of the form $f(\mathfrak{m_i})$ for a unique $i$. Also note that for an epimorphism every $f(\mathfrak{m})$ is either a maximal ideal or all of $S$:

Let $f(a)$ be in $S$, but not in $f(\mathfrak{m})$ (in particular $a \notin \mathfrak{m}$). Then it is $f(\mathfrak{m}) + f(a) = f(\mathfrak{m}+a) = S$

Note that two non-equal maximal ideals are always relatively prime. We get

$f(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \mathfrak{m}_i) = f(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{m}_i)= \prod_{i=1}^n f( \mathfrak{m}_i) = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} f(\mathfrak{m}_i) $

(generally (in the infinite case) we cannot change from intersections to products, so we only get an inclusion)

Comment: $J(R)$ is the intersection of maximal left Ideal of $R$.if we had finitely many maximal left Ideal then your answer is right but here we don't have finitely maximal left Ideal,we have finitely maximal Ideal,if I am wrong please explain it to me,that would be great.thank you.

Comment: I thought we're talking commutative rings (explicitly stated in the question) where (if I'm not totally mistaken) there's no distinction between right/left ideals. At least for me, doing commutative algebra, the Jacobson radical has always be defined as the intersection of all the maximal ideals.

Comment: I have seen theorem that was $J(R)\subseteq \bigcap \mathfrak{m}$ ,$\bigcap \mathfrak{m} $ is intersection of all maximal two sided Ideal.

Comment: yes,you're right,I didn't pay attention that our Rings are commutative.so in commutative Ring $J(R)\subseteq \bigcap \mathfrak{m} $ change to equality?

Comment: I'm using the Definition of the Jacobson Radical in Atiyah/MacDonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra, where the Jacobson radical of a commutative ring is defined to be the intersection of all the maximal ideals in $R$. However, as stated above, right/left ideals in commutative rings are equivalent, so the intersection over all left maximals is just the intersection over all maximals.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation.